# How to fix dent in tip of hood?

Tags: diy, hood, dent

I have a dent in the very tip of my Acura TLX's hood. It was dented in around 2 years ago when I accidentally let me car roll into a trailer hitch (this also crushed the logo, and grill, but I replaced those). Is there any way I could DIY this dent out without replacing the hood? I thought about hammering out the dent, but I don't think I could free-hand achieve the correct-looking tip. [image]

Comment: That is a difficult location to fix.  Pretty much an expensive traditional repair with painting the hood, or ignore it.

Comment: You could bang it back out, it may look worse that way as the metal will have been distorted.